# I want to not be able to run the same command twice very quickly

Tags: javascript, wait

So I have this chunk of code here:

```
lockskipCommand = (function(_super) {

__extends(lockskipCommand, _super);

function lockskipCommand() {
  return lockskipCommand.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

lockskipCommand.prototype.init = function() {
  this.command = '/lockskip';
  this.parseType = 'exact';
  return this.rankPrivelege = 'bouncer';
};

lockskipCommand.prototype.functionality = function() {
  data.lockBooth();
  new ModerationForceSkipService();
  return setTimeout((function() {
    return data.unlockBooth();
  }), 4500);
};

return lockskipCommand;

})(Command);
```

I want to be able to let it has some sort of cool down, so it can't be used quickly in a row. The reason I want this is to prevent from people being skipped, because that's what this chunk of code is for skipping people.

I hope this is enough information to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: This should help: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Underscore's [`debounce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) method (with `true` as the third argument).

If you don't want to include Underscore for this simple task, you could do...

```
var debounceFn = function (fn, delay) {
    var lastInvocationTime = Date.now();
    delay = delay || 0;

    return function () {
        (Date.now() - delay > lastInvocationTime) && (lastInvocationTime = Date.now()) && fn && fn();;
    };
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHxwU/).

> What I need is a way to not be able to execute the command more than once in a row.

You could do something similar...

```
var onceFn = function (fn) {
    var invoked = false;

    return function () {
        ! invoked && (invoked = true) && fn && fn();
    };
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fecRX/).

Comment: That's not what I need sadly :/ What I need is a way to not be able to execute the command more than once in a row. Like let's say I did /lockskip /lockskip I want the second /lockskip to not do anything. So that it doesn't have a double execution.

Comment: @NinjaMagii Gotcha, that should be easier. :)

Comment: I can't figure out how to use that for the life of me:/

Comment: @NinjaMagii Check the jsFiddle. It will wrap your existing function, so usage will be something like `var thisFunctionCanOnlyBeCalledOnce = function(function() { alert("once only!"); });`

Comment: @NinjaMagii Don't give up :) Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You know what I actually just got it today using a different way to do it! I made window.lastLockSkipTime and currentTime = new Date() in addition to milliseconds passed, to create a way to have a sort of cooldown as I wanted!